# Asset missing problem XNA

Tags: xna, 3d, textures, loading, microsoft

I'm using VS2010 with XNA 4.0 and I'm trying to load an FBX model with texture on the screen. The problem I'm having is this error:

**Missing Asset: C:\Users\ChocoMan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XNAGame\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\XNAGame\XNAGameContent\Textures\texture.bmp**

but the actual path to the texture is

**C:\Users\ChocoMan\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\XNAGame\XNAGameContent\Textures\texture.bmp**

Also, when I linked the texture in Maya, I used the above address.

Does anyone know why VS is looking for an incorrect address that doesnt exist?

Comment: Your model probably has relative path.

Comment: When you modeled your file, was the texture located in a different folder than the model? If so, you need to keep that relation.

Comment: @kikaimaru can you give me an idea of a relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In Maya (since I didnt create the model myself), I had to import the model, save it as an *.mb file, delete all but the default materials, apply the default lambert materials back to the model (because removing the texture made the model green), apply a new texture (phong in my case) and attach the UV map back on it, then export it again like normal into XNA. Now the model loads plus it's textured.